# Creating a countdown in v-for for each result

Tags: vue.js, countdown

I have a loop, in which I get several result from my API call.
Each of them has an property called `processing_time` that shows how many seconds it has left until something happens.

How can I implement the countdown for each interval?

Here is my `<progressbar>` component which needs a value for initially displaying the progress (I need it to be dynamic)

```html
<progress-bar :options="options"
  :value="data.properties.processing_time"
/>
<span class="progress-bar-seconds"
  >{{ data.properties.processing_time }} Seconds left
  ...</span>
```

I feel like I need to use `computed` but I don't exactly know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A computed prop is probably not the best solution, since you need to change the timer value locally. I recommend using a local copy that is updated periodically:

1. Create a local data property (a `ref`).
2. Copy the `value` prop to the local data prop upon mounting.
3. Use `setInterval` to periodically decrement the value.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="progress-bar-seconds">{{ seconds }} Seconds left ...</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const seconds = ref(0) // 1️⃣
    let _timerId = null

    onMounted(() => {
      seconds.value = props.value // 2️⃣
      if (seconds.value > 0) {
        // 3️⃣
        _timerId = setInterval(() => {
          seconds.value--
          if (seconds.value <= 0) {
            clearInterval(_timerId)
          }
        }, 1000)
      }
    })

    onUnmounted(() => clearInterval(_timerId))

    return { seconds }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/countdown-timer-in-vue-3-1bsn2?file=/src/components/ProgressBar.vue)